# ACF InnerBlocks breaks css grid, How can we add classes to allowedblocks (Wordpress Gutenberg)

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

When I create an ACF Innerblock with allowedblocks, childs blocks are wrapped inside a wp-block div that breaks my grid system.

For example a simple grid system like that :

```
<div class="grid-wrapper innerblock">
    
    <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>
    <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>
    <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>
    <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>

</div>
```

Will output this breaking code in the admin :

```
<div class="grid-wrapper block-editor-block-list__layout" data-is-drop-zone="true">
    
    <div class="wp-block"> <!-- no class "col3" !! -->  
        <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>
    </div>

    <div class="wp-block"> <!-- no class "col3" !! --> 
        <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>
    </div>

    <div class="wp-block"> <!-- no class "col3" !! -->
        <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>
    </div>

    <div class="wp-block"> <!-- no class "col3" !! -->
        <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>
    </div>


</div>
```

What's the solution to pass the class "col3" to the dynamics wp-blocks ?

I tried this, but it didn't work...

```
<div class="block-wrapper">

    <?php 
         $template = array( 
        array( "acf/card", array( "className" => "col1-6 col2-8 col3-4" ) ) 
         );

    ?>
        
    <InnerBlocks 
        class=" grid-wrapper" 
        allowedBlocks="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_json_encode( array( 'acf/card') ) ); ?> "
        template="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_json_encode( $template ) ); ?>"
    />



</div>
```

Comment: it would be interesting to know what exactly breaks. Can't you achieve your layout with the current HTML markup? There is hardly a layout that's impossible with grid.

Answer (score 0):

In InnerBlocks, I suspect `class=" grid-wrapper"` is breaking the layout as "class" is a reserved word in JavaScript. Unfortunately, InnerBlocks doesn't support "className" by default; even if you added `className="grid-wrapper` it would not be appended to class of `<div>...</div>`. Although, there is another way to create the wrapper `<div>` with the correct class using [hooks with InnerBlocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/#using-a-react-hook).

General InnerBlocks with `className` example:

**JavaScript**

```js
const blockProps = useBlockProps({
    className: "grid-wrapper"
});
    
const { children, ...innerBlocksProps } = useInnerBlocksProps(blockProps,
{
    template: [['acf/card', {className: 'col1-6 col2-8 col3-4'}]]
    allowedBlocks: ['acf/card']
});
    
// Outter div will have: class="grid-wrapper"   
<div {...innerBlocksProps}>
    {children} // Inner divs(blocks) will have: class="col1-6 col2-8 col3-4"
</div>
```